# User command with modified 'path' completion?

Tags: command-line, autocompletion, path, find

I'm trying to write a wrapper command around `:edit` or `:find` specifically to open either my vimrc or a subpath of `~/.vim/` (e.g. `~.vim/autoloads/foo.vim`).

If I run the command with no arguments, it should open `~/.vim/vimrc`. It should accept an argument to specify a subpath of `~/.vim/`, and provide tab completion of those subpaths.

I have something that works, but it feels overly complicated. I'm having to jump through hoops to tweak `'path'` before Vim's command completion kicks in.

```
let s:vimrc = resolve($MYVIMRC)
let s:vimrc_dir = fnamemodify(s:vimrc, ':h')

nnoremap <leader>f<CR> :call PreparePath()<CR>:EditDotVim 

command! -complete=file_in_path -nargs=? EditDotVim :
      \ call EditDotVim(<f-args>) |
      \ call RestorePath()

func! PreparePath()
  let s:orig_path = &l:path
  let s:orig_buf  = bufnr('')
  exec 'setl path='.s:vimrc_dir
endf

func! EditDotVim(...)
  execute 'edit' a:0 ? a:1 : s:vimrc
endf

func! RestorePath()
  call setbufvar(s:orig_buf, '&path', s:orig_path)
  unlet s:orig_path
  unlet s:orig_buf
endf
```

I was originally using a custom completion function and using the `find` shell builtin to provide completions, but given Vim's `'path'` variable and `:find` command, it seemed like I was reinventing the wheel.

Is there a more straightforward way to do this?

*UPDATE*

I'm still curious if there's a better way, but for now I've reverted to my original strategy, using custom completion and a little shell magic. I wouldn't call it slow, but it's not quite as snappy as I'd like, and I don't know how portable the `find` regex is. But it works for now. I moved this into my autoload directory:

```
let s:vimrc = resolve($MYVIMRC)
let s:vimrc_dir = fnamemodify(s:vimrc, ':h')

let s:sub_paths = [
      \ 'after',
      \ 'autoload',
      \ 'colors',
      \ 'compiler',
      \ 'ftdetect',
      \ 'ftplugin',
      \ 'indent',
      \ 'init',
      \ 'plugged',
      \ 'syntax',
      \ 'tmp',
      \ 'todo.org',
      \ 'view',
      \ 'vimrc'
      \]

let s:find_paths = '{'.join(s:sub_paths, ',').'}'

func! dotvim#edit(...)
  execute 'edit' (a:0 ? dotvim#path(a:1) : s:vimrc)
endf

func! dotvim#list(ArgLead, CmdLine, CursorPos)
  let findcmd = "find " . s:find_paths .  " -regex '".a:ArgLead."[^/]*' -exec ls -pd {} +"
  return system("cd " . s:vimrc_dir . " && " . findcmd)
endf

func! dotvim#path(subpath)
  return s:vimrc_dir . '/' . a:subpath
endf
```

I went back and forth on the hard-coded paths whitelist vs calling out to `ls` to generate it, vs using `find *` (if I do `find .` I get pesky leading `./` in my results), but ultimately the explicit whitelist makes it easy for me to tune which paths I actually care about.

Oh, and please ignore the `todo.org` file in there. I know it's a cardinal sin having even trace amounts of emacs in my `.vim/` ...

*UPDATE II*

Incorporating the `globpath` suggestion, this got a lot cleaner:

```
func! dotvim#list(ArgLead, CmdLine, CursorPos)
  return map(globpath(s:vimrc_dir, a:ArgLead.'*', 0, 1), s:subpath_map)
endf

let s:subpath_map = { k,v -> fnamemodify(v,':p')[(s:leading_len):] }
let s:leading_len = len(s:vimrc_dir) + 1

command! -complete=customlist,dotvim#list -nargs=? DotVim call dotvim#edit(<f-args>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom completion is indeed the way to go.

But why don't you use `globpath` instead of `system()`. Exploring directory hierarchies should much faster. Then you can filter results with `filter()`, and transform them with `map()`.

If you don't want to use exact paths, but recurse automatically, you can use `some/path/**`

NB: I resolve `.vim/` directory with [the following](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/path.vim#L555).

Comment: Great suggestion! I'll add an update with what I came up with. Also, I did wonder how best to resolve my `.vim/` directory. It's actually a git repo that I symlink from `~/.vim` and from `~/.config/nvim`

Comment: The idea behind my `lh#path#vimfiles()` function is to see what kind of pathnames we can find in `&rtp`. -> `.vim/` (every where, but...), `vimfiles/` (...windows), or `.config/nvim` (...neovim). Also, I'm able to work in shared accounts (which is a very bad thing to do!) where I reserve myself a `~/luc/.vim/` directory to store my vim settings.

Answer (score 3):

```
nnoremap <leader>f<CR> :EditVim ~/.vim/**/*
command! -complete=file_in_path -nargs=? EditVim : call EditVim (<f-args>)

func! EditVim(...)
    if a:0 == 0 || a:1 ==? '~/.vim/**/*'
        execute 'edit ~/.vimrc'
    else
        execute 'edit' a:1
    endif
endf
```

[image: demo]

Here the `~/.vim/**/*foo` pattern will match anything that has `foo` and is located in `~/.vim/` or any of its subfolders recursively. Given that you want the completion, I assume that you only need this wrapper command for quick navigation to your config files. If so, then you could just use these mappings instead:

```
nnoremap <leader>F :edit ~/.vimrc<CR>
nnoremap <leader>f :edit ~/.vim/**/*
```

Comment: This looks promising! I just digested the other answer and incorporated its ideas into my current solution. I'll take another look at this approach too. Thanks